# How to handle duplicate tags when creating tag in Asana API

Tags: asana

I am using the Ruby Wrapper "Asana" to create an integration with Asana API. One problem when I test the Tag creation through CURL is that it seems Asana doesn't take care of duplicating Tags. i.e. when I do the following command twice. It will generate two tags with different tag ID. Can Asana detect duplicate Tags and merge tasks together?

```
curl -u <my_api_key>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags \
    -d "name=Test Tag" \
    -d "workspace=123123123"
```

1st Response:

```
{"data":{"id":11800363445095,"created_at":"2014-04-22T10:03:19.888Z","name":"Test Tag","notes":"","....:[]}}%
```

2nd Response:

```
{"data":{"id":11800365867646,"created_at":"2014-04-22T10:03:27.501Z","name":"Test Tag","notes":"","....:[]}}%
```

Note that although the Tags have the same name, but they have different IDs. But what I want is if a task is created with same tag name, it will fall back on the previous tag ID.

Answer (score 0):

Tags, like Projects, are true objects in Asana - they have their own ID, database entry, properties and so forth, *even if they have the same name*.

This is of course different from other implementations of tags you may be familiar with - and we're aware of that and looking for ways to make tags be uniquely identified by name and workspace, like people expect, but that's not in the immediate pipeline.

So for now you can work around this by first getting the tag list and creating it if no tag by that name exists. Of course that's not atomic, and it's inelegant, but it's a potential workaround.

A general wrapper for the API should probably assume the same semantics as the API, rather than try to hide them, though.